# Syntax for resolving incompatible property type on inherited delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, protocols

Some code I inherited has an annoying warning.  It declares a protocol and then uses that to specify the delegate

```
@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate;

@interface MyTextField: UITextField
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
@optional
- (void)myTextFieldSomethingHappened:(MyTextField *)textField;
@end
```

Classes which use `myTextField` implement the `MyTextFieldDelegate` and are called it with this code:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myTextFieldSomethingHappened:)])
{
    [delegate myTextFieldSomethingHappened:self];
}
```

This works, but creates the (legitimate) warning: *warning: property type 'id' is incompatible with type 'id' inherited from 'UITextField'*

Here are the solutions I've come up with:

1. Remove the property.  This works but I get the warning *'-myTextFieldSomethingHappened:' not found in protocol(s)*
2. Drop the protocol entirely.  No warnings, but you also lose the semantic warnings if you forget to implement the protocol in the delegate.

Is there a way to define the delegate property such that the compiler is happy?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

try:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<UITextFieldDelegate,MyTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: Brilliant, and makes total sense.

Comment: I finally (two years after asking the question, and one year after getting a clear answer) got around to fixing this in my code. I just wanted to say "spot on and thanks".

Answer (score 5):

UITextField has also got property named [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/delegate), but it has another type. Just rename your `delegate` property to something else.

Comment: This would create more risks than using delegate and eschewing the syntax check.

Comment: I absolutely don't understand what risks do you mean.

Comment: Having two fields which act as the delegate is a maintenance risk; it would be too easy for someone to use the code and reference the wrong delegate field.

Comment: That's why I told you to rename it. It's absolutely normal for class to have several delegates (UITableView for example has delegate and dataSource properties).

Comment: You are correct that there are often multiple delegates, especially when the serve different purposes; this is a traditional call-back "delegate" and I would not want to add delegate2, extendedDelegate, or any other almost-delegate name.  I eventually used dropped the protocol from the delegate, relying on the [xyzzy respondsTo:] test.  I had been hoping there was a syntax that communicated my specifications to the compiler.  As yours is the only reply, I'll accept it as the solution if you can edit it to indicate no known syntax for my question.  Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer in UITableView.h.

The UIScrollView has property name delegate, and the UITableView has the same name property.

```
@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>
// Your code
......

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

The original problem is that there is no information about MyTextFieldDelegate's inheritance during declaration of **delegate** property. It's caused by forward declaration of protocol (@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate;).

I've faced the same problem but with protocol declaration in the other .h file. In my case solution was just to #import appropriate header.

In your case you just need to swap the order of declaration:

```
@class MyTextField;

@protocol MyTextFieldDelegate <UITextFieldDelegate>
@optional
- (void)myTextFieldSomethingHappened:(MyTextField *)textField;
@end

@interface MyTextField : UITextField
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyTextFieldDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Comment: I also need to add @dynamic in implementation to dismiss the warning