# Property type 'id' is incompatible with type 'id' inherited from 'UIToolbar' warning

Tags: ios

I just installed xcode 5 and I'm now receiving this warning. I've never seen it before. My app runs fine, but I hate seeing a warning.  Does anyone know what this is and how to fix it?
Thanks

Property type 'id' is incompatible with type 'id' inherited from 'UIToolbar'

Comment: No code required. This error is self-explaining.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax for resolving incompatible property type on inherited delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188707/syntax-for-resolving-incompatible-property-type-on-inherited-delegate)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the lack of context, but this appears to be a duplicate of [Syntax for resolving incompatible property type on inherited delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188707/syntax-for-resolving-incompatible-property-type-on-inherited-delegate)

The problem is likely that you are creating a new property with the same name but with different protocols attached.

For example, `UIToolBar` has the following property:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIToolbarDelegate> delegate;
```

If you were to declare the below in your class, it would generate this warning because the two properties have different protocols:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MyBetterDelegate> delegate;
```

There are two ways to solve this.  You could modify your protocol to inherit from the other protocol:

```
@protocol MyBetterDelegate<UIToolbarDelegate>
...
```

Or you could modify your property definition to capture both protocols:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<MyBetterDelegate, UIToolbarDelegate> delegate;
```

Comment: This did the trick.  thanks!  There are two ways to solve this. You could modify your protocol to inherit from the other protocol:

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's because you might be declaring an id property in your class named delegate and UIToolbar has a property id with the same name. Just change the name of your class for something like myClassDelegate and it will clear the warning.

[Syntax for resolving incompatible property type on inherited delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188707/syntax-for-resolving-incompatible-property-type-on-inherited-delegate)

Answer (score -1):

You should not use "id" as property in your objects - it's reserved for objective C objects.

Change it to something like "toolbarId" - than it's fine.

Comment: There is - you are doing it wrong :) Especially if your "id" type is different than it should be.

Comment: Whops, you are right. I have read fast and I hadn't understand the question, but undoubtedly you are right